# Background-position: Not applying to mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, background-position

I'm doing some responsive work and can not figure out why this isnt applying to my phones browsers.

Heres what I'm using to shift the images (They shift properly on desktop when I scale down)

```
 .element {
    background-image: url("/image");
    min-height: 1000px;
    background-position: 0% 100%;
 }
```

So, this looks perfect on desktop when I scale down to it.. However, If I load it up in Chrome/Safari on my IPhone6.. The position does not take effect.. The background and the min-height change.

For reference, the height of the image is much taller than the min-height.

I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Your code doesn't show you are shifting an image. It may be a portion of your code, but we need more to go on. Put your HTML, and your full CSS (Not the whole enchilada, just the all that pertains to this alleged shift)

Comment: Can you add a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) example to the question? Otherwise people who want to help you have to spend time recreating the setup to test with.

Comment: Try to replace to `backround-position:left bottom`